# Extend user to have many medications

Tags: django

I would like to save many medications to the Profile like so.

models.py

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):
    

class Medications(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile,related_name='user',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(default='',max_length=100)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    per_time = models.IntegerField()
    time_choices = (('other', 'Other'),('Post meal', 'Post meal'),('Breakfast' ,'Breakfast'))
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=time_choices,default='others')
```

forms.py

```
class MedicationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True, help_text='Required.')
    amount = forms.IntegerField( required=True, help_text='Required.')
    class Meta:
        model = Medications
        fields = ('name','amount','per_time','choice')
```

**Now in here I would like to create a Medication with the request user. I used if form.is_valid(): form.save() which just gives IntegrityError at /addMed/
NOT NULL constraint failed: pages_medications.user_id which needs to be from request.user**

```
@login_required
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def addMed(request):
    print('Adding med')
    print(request.user)
    print(request.POST)
    med = MedicationForm(request.POST or None,)
    print(med)
    return redirect('medications')
```

Which gives

```
Adding med
user
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['-'], 'name': ['Tylenol'], 'amount': ['1'], 'per_time': ['1'], 'choice': ['other'], 'medicationForm': ['Upload']}>
```

Then list all the medications in here.

views.py

```
@login_required
def medications(request):
    context={}  
    context['nmenu'] = 'medications'
    context['medicationForm'] = MedicationForm()
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign the logged in user to the `Medications` object:

```
@login_required
@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def addMed(request):
    med = MedicationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    med.instance.user = request.user
    med.save()
    return redirect('medications')
```

Comment: That seems to work. How would I go about filtering it just use Medications.objects.filter(user=request.user) Just waiting for the time to go down to accept it.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan: indeed, with this `QuerySet`, you get the `Medications` related to the logged in user.